# Exception handling with user input when several inputs in a row is required

Tags: java, exception, user-input

I am working on a program where the user can add persons as well as vehicles. The program is functioning to the requirements of the scholl assignment, however I want it to work even better by handling exceptions if the user puts in an invalid statement.

I have this and it works by having the user be put back into the menu of the program so the program does not crash, but I do not want the user to have to restart the process of adding an object all over again, but rather retry from the excact place where the error occured.

Here is the code:

```
    // adds person to registry
public void addPerson(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Name of person: ");
        String name = Main.sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Age of person: ");
        int age = Main.sc.nextInt();
        Main.sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("City of residence: ");
        String city = Main.sc.nextLine();
        Person person = new Person(name, age, city);
        personList.add(person);
    }catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Not a valid input. Try again");
        Main.sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

The error will occur if the user types in anything but integers in the "Enter age:" question.

I have another method for adding vehicles that takes alot more user input and in that method in particular it would be pretty bad if the user has to start all over again.

How to fix that?

Comment: Extract each part asking for one piece of information into its own method that asks the information, validates it, and asks it again until it's correct. Your addPerson() method would boil down to `personList.add(new Person(askName(), askAge(), askCity()));`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper method:

```
public int askInt(String prompt) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        try {
            return Main.sc.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer number.");
        }
    }
}
```

NB: Your mixing of `nextLine` and `next`<whatever> indicates you aren't using Scanner correctly; you should either use only the one or only the other. If you wish to ask the user for inputs that can contain spaces, configure the scanner to split inputs on newlines instead of 'any whitespace'. Do this by calling `sc.useDelimiter("\r?\n")` immediately after creating it, and to retrieve a string, simply call `next()`. This will retrieve the entire line.